# elasticsearch reducing result to one column - return only 1 value for each document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I try to reduce the json result of elasticsearch to only the column or columns i suggested to get. Is there any way?

When I use the following command, I get the result nasted into "_source":

```
 {
 "from": "0", "size":"2",
 "_source":["id"],
 "query": {                           
  "match_all": {}
  }
 }
 '
```

and there is no need for my use case.

I get this result:

```
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "indexer_1",
        "_type" : "type_indexer_1",
        "_id" : "38142",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 38142
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexer_1",
        "_type" : "type_indexer_1",
        "_id" : "38147",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 38147
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I would like to have:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "id" : 38142
      },
      {
        "id" : 38147
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And this json-result I would love:

```
{
  {
    "id" : 38142
  },
  {
    "id" : 38147
  }
}
```

Is there any way out of the box in ES to reduce the result set?

Comment: check this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968200/exclude-id-and-index-field-in-elasticsearch-result-data

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the output JSON look at the documentation : [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering)

```
GET /index/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._id
 {
 "from": "0", 
 "size":"2",
 "_source":["id"],
 "query": {                           
  "match_all": {}
  }
 }
```

Comment: this does work until the _id is the same like _source,id
But not excact what I wanted.

Comment: yes according to your question _id is same as id